# Extend asp.net session timeout to 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i am developing asp webapplication as well as a website using webforms. i have 3 to 4 sessions in the whole application. e.g Session["Rate"], session["webinformation"], session["userinformation"] . my problem is that i want to extend the timeout of only session["Rate"] to 24 hours approximately, doing that in **webconfig** file does not help me. How can i do this in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store and expire after 5 minutes (you can modify it to 24 hours)

```
Session.AddWithTimeout("key", "value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Get the stored value

```
Session.GetWithTimeout("key");
```

You can find the source code [here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/196-aspnet-session-caching-expiring-values/)

Comment: "key" is my session name? and value?

Comment: e.g. Session["Rate"] = 128. key: name of session (in this case "Rate") and value is the object/ value (in this case 128) you would like to store in the session.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)